# long background process refreshing ui wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await

I have long search operations which periodically updates UI (found occurence -> Update UI)

I've tried to realize it many ways:

1. async/await

   ```
   public void PushButton()
   {
       await AsyncSearchAll();
   }

   public async Task AsyncSearchAll(SearchPanelViewModel searchPanelViewModel, SearchSettings searchSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                         {
                                             //searching for occurence
                                             //write it into panel
                                         }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
   }
   ```
2. BackgroundWorker

   I want to use it but I don't want access UI using only .ReportProgress()
3. Simple background thread with calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{//updating UI})`

   ```
   /// <summary>
   ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           var backgroundThread = new Thread(CountToTen)
               {
                   IsBackground = true
               };
           backgroundThread.Start();
       }

       private void CountToTen()
       {
           for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
           {
               var j = i;
               Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Seconds.Text = j.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
           }
       }
   ```

All methods writing all data after completing thread.
Is there any method to run background task which periodically updating UI without slowing program by blocking ui?

Comment: Which method provide desired result?

Comment: 2 and 3 are. But if ReportProgress is not enough for you, then use Dispatcher.

Comment: Please show us the simple code for (3), that does not work properly

Comment: Regarding 1st, it should NOT be running on the UI thread (which assume the 'current context' will be) and using `IProgress<T>` or Dispatcher to notify the UI...

Comment: We're using the background thread with a reporter, just like you have suggested in #3. We have two tricks, though: interpolation for long parts during which the progress is indeterminate, and event filtering to suppress additional updates if they are too frequent (we use Reactive Extensions to filter the event stream).

Comment: I've put example at 3 method so you can see that updating appears after method was finished

Comment: 'Seconds' is TextBox on the form

Comment: How do you suppose to see the changes, if you have no pause in `CountToTen()`. Add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to every iteration. Your example is fully functional.

Answer (score 4):

It's best if you can separate your "worker" logic from your "UI update" logic.

Something like this:

```
public async Task AsyncSearchAll(SearchPanelViewModel searchPanelViewModel, SearchSettings searchSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (..)
  {
    var results = await Task.Run(() => /* search more */);
    /* update panel with results */
  }
}
```

But if you want actual progress updates, there's ways to do that too:

```
public async void PushButton()
{
  Progress<MyUpdateType> progress = new Progress<MyUpdateType>(update =>
  {
    /* update panel */
  });
  await Task.Run(() => SearchAll(..., progress));
}

public void SearchAll(SearchPanelViewModel searchPanelViewModel,
    SearchSettings searchSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    IProgress<MyUpdateType> progress)
{
  while (..)
  {
    /* search more */
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(new MyUpdateType(...));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in cases like this, it's best if you can use binding. With the [new collection synchronization](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux), you can do things like adding to a bound `ObservableCollection<T>` from another thread.

If that's not enough for your purposes, you can use `Progress<T>` to perform an action on the UI thread whenever your produce some result on the other thread (though, as its name suggests, `Progress` is primarily meant for progress reporting).

If that doesn't fit either, you could use TPL Dataflow. You would have a single `ActionBlock<T>` with `TaskScheduler` set to the UI scheduler. Your worker thread would send the generated items to the block and the block would process them on the UI thread.